# Add a gif video file in UIWebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, gif

[image]

[image]

I'm adding a GIF image in `UIWbeview` in Objective-C. The problem is that the image size doesn't fit in the screen and the contents above the gif video is not showing. How can I adjust the image size and show the buttons above it.

My code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"back" ofType:@"gif"];
    NSData *gif = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    
    UIWebView *webViewBG = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [webViewBG loadData:gif MIMEType:@"gif" textEncodingName:NULL baseURL:NULL];
    webViewBG.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    webViewBG.scalesPageToFit=YES;
    [self.view addSubview:webViewBG];
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: GIF is an Image, not Video. You question is not clear, add some screenshots with more descriptions.

Comment: please share the screenShot of the VC

Comment: https://medium.com/swift-programming?source=logo-lo_70f977b2b7e9---5396e0e8bc29 . Im following this. @iphonic

Comment: check  the screen shot. @Md.IbrahimHassan

Comment: Please attach the simulator ScreenShot with the app running and not the code screenshot

Comment: it is only appearing white screen in simulator. @Md.IbrahimHassan

Comment: that means your gif is not loading

Comment: yup can u help? @Md.IbrahimHassan

Comment: @NAVEEN KUMAR can u help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move your code to `viewDidAppear`

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated  {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"back" ofType:@"gif"];
    NSData *gif = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    UIWebView *webViewBG = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [webViewBG loadData:gif MIMEType:@"image/gif" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:NULL];
    webViewBG.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    webViewBG.scalesPageToFit=YES;
    [self.view addSubview:webViewBG];
}
```

Comment: can u help me? @Luan Tran

Comment: When you use `viewDidAppear`, did trigger go to that function ?

Comment: The error is interface for UIViewController declare the selector 'viewDidAppear'. @Luan Tran

Comment: its not working blank screen is coming and the contents above the web view are not visible. @Luan Tran

Comment: Can you check again? I used `MIMEType:@"image/gif"` and `textEncodingName:@"UTF-8"`

Comment: its working but an issue is coming that it is not fit in whole screen. @Luan Tran

Comment: Can you take a screenshot for current result?

Comment: bro plzz help. @Luan Tran

Comment: how about gif source. What size is it?

Comment: its 34MB . @Luan Tran

Comment: My mean is your gif width & height ?

Comment: 1920 × 1080 . @Luan Tran

Comment: Let add `webViewBG.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill`. or `scaleAspectFit`. :)